# Why is my custom block name not being generated?

Tags: views

I created a custom block called "Heading, Body, and Link" and the name being suggested for the Twig template in the source code is `block--block-content--72dacf39-0242-4eaa-9226-171add6f87d2.html.twig`

The field names are being generated correctly.

Why is this happening and how can I get Drupal to use/generate the human-readable name?

[image: source code]

Comment: I figured this out in case anyone has the same issue:

If I add the block to the custom block library and then add it to a page later it doesn't show up with the human-readable name. However, if I create the block while adding it to a page it'll show up with the desired human-readable name based on the block name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.